# Table with fixed layout within scroll container not consuming defined width

Tags: html, css

I need to put a table with a fixed layout and fixen column width in a scrollable container. The table and its single columns should consume the space defined in the colgroup section.

This is the html:

```
<div class="scroll-container">

  <table>
    <colgroup>
      <col width="100px">
      <col width="100px">
      <col width="50px">
    </colgroup>

    <tr>
      <td>width &lt; 100px</td>    
      <td>width &lt; 1 100px</td>   
      <td>width &lt; 150px</td>   
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

And this the css:

```
div.scroll-container{
  width : 200px;
  height : 90px;
  background-color : #ddd;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

table{
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td{
   border : 1px solid black;

}
```

The widths of the columns is shrinking and the div container is not scrolling whereas I want to achieve the opposite.

Js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n337p1ck/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just have to add:

```
width:100%;
```

to your table

```css
div.container{
  width : 260px;
  height : 70px;
  background-color : #ccc;
}

div.scroll-container{
  width : 200px;
  height : 90px;
  background-color : #ddd;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

table{
  table-layout: fixed;
  width:100%;
}

td{
   border : 1px solid black;
   
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <table>
    <colgroup>
      <col width="100px">
      <col width="100px">
      <col width="50px">
    </colgroup>

    <tr>
      <td>width = 100px</td>    
      <td>width = 100px</td>   
      <td>width = 50px</td>   
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>

<hr/>

<div class="scroll-container">

  <table>
    <colgroup>
      <col width="100px">
      <col width="100px">
      <col width="50px">
    </colgroup>

    <tr>
      <td>width &lt; 100px</td>    
      <td>width &lt; 1 100px</td>   
      <td>width &lt; 150px</td>   
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: great, that was easy :-) Thanks!